Linear series on plane cubic curve
I am struggling to understand linear series on curves. All I know it is that if $D$ is a divisor of degree $n$ on a curve $C$ then a $g_n^r$ is the set of effective divisors associated to a $r+1$ dimensional subspace of $O(D)$.
Why is the following sentence true:
“The $g_3^2$ cut out by the lines on a plane cubic with one node is not complete, since it is contained in the $g_3^3$ cut out on $C$ by the conics through the node and another point.”
